# How to find a polynomial that passes through a fixed number of points in non-monotonic order?

Tags: python, numpy, math, polynomials

I have lists of X and Y coordinates of different objects (up to 5 objects maximum, 0 minimum). I want to plot a smooth polynomial connecting them in their correct order. All the examples I have seen so far require the X-values to be in strictly increasing order. One of my attempts is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xlist = [4, 5, 4.5] # x-coordinates
ylist = [4,7,10] # y-coordinates

z = np.polyfit(xlist, ylist, 2)
f = np.poly1d(z)

xx = np.linspace(np.array(xlist).min(),np.array(xlist).max(),100)
plt.plot(xlist, ylist, 'ob')
plt.plot(xx, f(xx))
plt.show
```

[image]

This result is of course not what I wanted, as the order is ignored.

I have also looked into using cubic splines but facing a similar issue with the order.

Edit: Here is what I want my result to look like:

[image: example of what I want]

Comment: if you need the x's to be in increasing order, why not sorting the [x,y] together using x as the key?

Comment: To clarify this, please draw us an image of what you expect. This sounds impossible (with an ordinary polynomial mapping a real number to a real number (rather than mapping a real number to a 2D coordinate, i.e., a pair of real numbers)).

Comment: Please draw what you would like instead. The following is based on what I can suspect from the question so far... I have the feeling you are not looking for a function. The definition of a function prohibits that `f(a)!=f(b)` for `a=b`, basically meaning that you can not have two funciton graphs "above" each other. This means that the order in that the function goes through your `(x,y)` points **has to** happen based on the order of your `x` values. Otherwise you'll need to go back to x-values for which you already defined your function, which is "prohibited".

Comment: @André You mean they're not looking for a *real* function. You can certainly do it with others.

Comment: @Kelly That's true, meant to write "polynomial". Effectively, I guess OP is looking to fit some kind of [parametric curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) of whatever shape.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have added an image showing what I want the result to be, as an example.